# object name is in no quotes and object properties are in quotes

Tags: javascript

as a newbie to Javascript  i read this

```
Object.defineProperty(person1, "name", {
    enumerable: false
});
```

I want to know why the person1 Object is not in quotes and the property name is.
is this a fact that every time we mention a property somewhere we have to use quotes around it? thanks.

Comment: If you put quotes on object, that is no longer a variable referencing to a location, it'll be a string

Comment: `person1` is a variable, whereas `"name"` is a string

Answer (score 0):

"name" is a string so you need to put it inside the quotes. But when you put quotes on object ie, `person1` then it would behave as string literal and not as object.